# Как сгенерировать json?

Tags: python, json

Как создать объект json так, чтобы внутри по ключу находился еще и архив?
Пробую методом генерации, но получаю строку, которую `json.dumps()` не воспринимает:

```
pole = {
    "recordsFiltered": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "history_money": "-11 часов",
        "history_text": "НОМЕР: 79089688399 Абонет: Доступен"
      },
      {
        "history_money": "+11 часов",
        "history_text": "НОМЕР: 79189688399 Абонет: Доступен"
      }
    ]
}

print(pole['data'][0]['history_money'])
```

Я хочу добавлять в обьект 'data': array

Мой метод реализации:

```
import json

pol = {"history_money": "-11 часов", "history_text": "НОМЕР: 79089688399 Абонет: Доступен"}
rep = {"recordsFiltered":1,"data":"" + str(pol) + ""} 

print(rep)
print(rep['data'][0]['history_money'])
```

В итоге получаю или ошибку, или пустой массив:

```
{'recordsFiltered': 1, 'data': []}
```

Comment: А где у вас тут вообще json ? У вас тут обычные питоновские словари, так что `rep = { ...., "data":  [ pol ] }` включит массив из одного элемента, объекта pol, в элемент data словаря rep

Comment: rep воспринимается пакетом json.
Т.к в конечном итоге нужно получить json обьект

Comment: А откуда вы этот json берете ? Если откуда то извне, то парсите его в объект через json.loads(), объекты включайте куда надо, по обычным правилам питона, например добавляя в массив с помощью append. Если на выходе потом опять нужен json, то преобразуете ваш объект с помощью json.dumps

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то просто добавляете словарь в словарь, обернув его в список: `"data": [pol]`

```
import json

pol = {"history_money": "-11 часов", "history_text": "НОМЕР: 79089688399 Абонет: Доступен"}
rep = {"recordsFiltered":1,"data": [pol]} 
print(rep)
print(rep['data'][0]['history_money'])

js = json.dumps(rep, ensure_ascii=False)
print(js)
```

Вывод:

```
{'recordsFiltered': 1, 'data': [{'history_money': '-11 часов', 'history_text': 'НОМЕР: 79089688399 Абонет: Доступен'}]}
-11 часов
{"recordsFiltered": 1, "data": [{"history_money": "-11 часов", "history_text": "НОМЕР: 79089688399 Абонет: Доступен"}]}
```

Comment: Да такое работает, и добавляется по ключю в обьект.
Но как добавить два и более обьекта по одному ключю.

Comment: @RustamAksenov Дальше у вас уже есть там список, можете добавлять в него: `rep['data'].append(something)`